# Google App Engine features

Tags: google-app-engine

Its mid-April 2011. I spent quite a bit of time looking at Google App Engine last summer. What, if anything, has changed about it since then? Are there any new features, any revisions to old features, are people using it more now for live apps or less? Looking at the docs its hard to see what's different (other than App Engine for Business).

Comment: Just read [roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html), [release notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes). Lot of cool stuff there, Channel API, High replication datastore, increasing timeouts, dedicated instances, a unit-testing tool.  Python 2.7 + domain backed SSL on the roadmap.

Answer (score 2):

See a list of major feature releases at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html

I've been using it for my app and have had very little service disruption.  It scales as promised, and if they deliver on some upcoming features it'll be even greater.  I haven't used any other services, but decided on appengine in the fall, and I've never regretted it.

While I'm outing myself as a fanboy, I'll also mention that the documentation has steadily improved, and there are youtube videos of google i/o that are really fantastic resources.